# Sessions over multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have a table that has start_time, end_time (both timestamp) for an ID. The sessions can be contiguous and appear over multiple rows but each session can be belong to 2 additional columns. I am trying to find the session length for a single day, for a given set of columns.

Input Table:

```
ID   Start                   End          Website  Webpage     
U1  11/02/17 10:27:14   11/02/17 10:27:20     W1    P1        
U1  11/02/17 10:27:40   11/02/17 10:27:51     W1    P1        
U2  11/02/17 10:27:20   11/02/17 10:27:38     W2    P2        
U2  11/02/17 10:41:20   11/02/17 10:41:50     W3    P3        
U3  11/02/17 10:27:20   11/02/17 10:27:51     W2    P2        
U1  11/04/17 9:27:30    11/04/17 9:28:30      W1    P1
```

**How to get the below Desired output?**

```
ID    Website  Webpage     time_diff   start_time
U1    W1         P1         17         11/02/17
U2    W2         P2         18         11/02/17
U2    W3         P3         30         11/02/17
U3    W2         P2         31         11/02/17
U1    W1         P1         60         11/04/17
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us nicely what you want to do, now show us what you have done? where is the code you have tried?

Comment: MAX, MIN functions with GROUP BY on ID, Website, Webpage should do the trick. You should try to write that, it is simple enough.

Comment: One correction- the time_diff column does not exist. I am calculating that on the fly. Made correction to input table to reflect this.

Comment: Is the time difference for U1, W1, P1 going to be 17 or 37 ? If 17 then use SUM(End - Start) and GROUP BY ID, Website, Webpage. If 37 then use MAX, MIN as I said above. Why don't you try something?

Comment: Those are star and end times- so no they cannot be 37. They are sum of sessions and 17. I have been trying different variations like the one below. It didn't work hence the question post :)
select t.id, t.Website, t.Webpage, DATEDIFF(second, t.start_time, t.end_time) as time_diff from input_table t 
group by t.id, t.website, t.webpage, t.start_time, t.end_time. 
Note all those columns in group by are being required by SQL to be included. The query throws errors if those columns are missing.

Comment: The problem is as soon as I add the DATEDIFF() in the select statement, I must use a gropu by on both the start_time and end_time columns. This then takes away the granularity of multiple sessions recorded on the same day. And has an additional problem of not being able to get a daily breakdown. The table above is a sample and in reality, I have multiple sessions that go over just one day as well as multiple days for the same user. Ideally I want to get a: per user, per day aggregated session length, per website, webpage combination

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to post the answer for this.
This query worked. Thanks all for the help.

```
SELECT ID, Website, Webpage, SUM(DATEDIFF(second,start,end)) 
AS time_diff, DATE(Start) as start_time
from web_sessions_table
GROUP BY 
start_time, ID,
Webpage,
Website
```